# Watermark Html.TextBox in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, watermark

I am using mvc4 framework i need to water mark `@Html.TextBox("Name")`. How to do this. Could you please place the latest method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it another way,

An email input field and css watermark class.

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.watermark { color: #999; } //light silver color
</style>

<label>Email : </lable>
<input id="email" type="text" />
```

jQuery to apply the watermark effect on email field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var watermark = 'Puts your email address';

    //init, set watermark text and class
    $('#email').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

    //if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
    $('#email').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    //if focus and text is watermrk, set it to empty and remove the watermark class
    $('#email').focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == watermark){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use attribute "placeholder". Here is how it should look like in razor:

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", "Value", new { placeholder = "Enter name" })
```

Comment: I have tried like this but getting Html.textbox value like this " { placeholder = Enter name } "

Comment: You need to specify value, if you want to add HTML attributes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: can you give any examples i would appreciate you

Comment: I couldn't understand please clarify it.

Comment: Answer is edited, try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Give this jQuery plugin a go:

http://plugins.jquery.com/watermark/

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", @Model.Name /*Value or NULL*/, new { placeholder = "PLACEHOLDER TEXT" })
```